# How can I cast double[] to System.Windows.Media.DoubleCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Is there any way to to it without copying values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the values will need to be copied, but [`DoubleCollection` has a constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589472.aspx) that'll do it automatically for you:

```
var foo = new double[] { 1.0, 2.5, 3.3, 4.1, 5.9 };
var bar = new DoubleCollection(foo);
```

**EDIT...**

You've specified that you're using Silverlight, which means that there's no such constructor available. In that case you'll need to do all the work yourself (not that it actually requires much extra work):

```
var foo = new double[] { 1.0, 2.5, 3.3, 4.1, 5.9 };
var bar = new DoubleCollection();
foreach (double d in foo) bar.Add(d);

// or, if you prefer Array.ForEach to a foreach loop...
// Array.ForEach(foo, d => bar.Add(d));
```

Comment: Tried your code. Got "'System.Windows.Media.DoubleCollection' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments." although there is such constructor in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.doublecollection_members.aspx.

Comment: Understood what's wrong. I'm using Silverlight, not full .NET framework.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer is no.

The `DoubleCollection` has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589472.aspx) that takes `IEnumerable<Double>` that you can use:

```
DoubleCollection dc = new DoubleColection(myArray);
```

This will still create a copy of each value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [constructor of DoubleCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589472.aspx) to do this, but under the covers, that might just be copying values, so I would reflect it to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
DoubleCollection dCollection = new DoubleColection(myDoubleArray);
```